# jQuery trigger mousedown touchstart event after keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm setting up an AJAX form that is detecting click and keydown events.

I was having trouble registering clicks on mobile, so I switched the .click() function to "mousedown touchstart"

```
$("signUpBtnNew").click(function() {
```

to

```
$(document).on("mousedown touchstart", "#signUpBtnNew", function() {
```

Now, I'd like to add a keydown event to trigger the "mousedown touchstart" function, but not sure how to do this:

```
$('#acct_email').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        // change this to use the mousedown touchstart
        $("#signUpBtnNew").click(); 
    }
});
```

how do I simulate a "mousedown touchstart" event in the keydown function above?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not putting it into a external function and calling it from $('#acct_email').on('keydown', function(e) {}); and from $(document).on("mousedown touchstart", "#signUpBtnNew", function() {});